# ENABLE and T/R pins on MAX7032 Tranciever

Tags: voltage, pins, transceiver

Last month I started working with electronics a bit. With no previous knowledge and I'm getting into PCB design for many different applications.
That being said please correct me if I misinterpret or miss anything.

I want to use the MAX7032 transceiver as a transmitter. I'm having trouble connecting some pins which are the Transmit/Receive pin and the ENABLE pin which I believe both need to be active high according to the description and the application I want to use them for. This is their description  below:

> -T/R. Drive high to put the device in transmit mode. Drive low or leave unconnected to
> put the device in receive mode. It is internally pulled down. This function is also controlled by a configuration register.

I interpret this as Transmit is connected to a Voltage and Receive is ground.

> -ENABLE. Drive high for normal operation. Drive low or leave unconnected to put the device into
> shutdown mode.

I interpret this as drive high or die?

I found that under absolute maximum ratings the "ENABLE, T/R, DATA, CS, DIO, SCLK, CLKOUT to
GND...-0.3V to (HVIN + 0.3V)"

My HVIN is 3.0 V

So the voltage supplied to Enable and T/R can be 2.7-3.3 V?

Link to [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7032.pdf).

Comment: Don't make the all-too-common noob mistake of thinking you can operate an IC anywhere near it's "Absolute Maximum" rating on any parameter. Ignore them. Pretend you didn't see them. They're not relevant to anything you're going to do with that IC. If you just can't bear to to that, then *read the paragraph of text below them* where it tells you "These are stress ratings only, and functional operation of the device at these ... specifications is not implied. Exposure to absolute maximum rating conditions for extended periods may affect device reliability."

Comment: Thanks I didn't read the fine print, your comment is exactly why I asked this question. I have a 3.7v battery  on hand and I'm gonna try and find a buck converter that will drop the voltage down to 2 volts since the typical voltage of the IC is 2.7V. Would that be a good solution? TPS51463RGER is one I found on mouser that might work

Answer (score 0):

The Abs Max on that pin is typical of what you see for many digital input pins. There are probably ESD structures from that pin to HVIN and to GND. if you go too far above HVIN or below GND you'll turn the ESD diodes on and damage them.

You can safely connect ENABLE and TR to HVIN and forget about them forever.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the response.